# iOS animate/morph shape from circle to square

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

I try to change a circle into a square and vice versa and I am almost there. However it doesn't animates as expected. I would like all corners of a square to be animated/morphed at the same time but what I get is the following:

[image]

I use `CAShapeLayer` and `CABasicAnimation` in order to animate shape property.

Here is how I create the circle path:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)circlePathWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius
{    
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI/2 clockwise:YES];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:M_PI/2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:3*M_PI/2 clockwise:YES];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:3*M_PI/2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
    [circlePath closePath];
    return circlePath;
}
```

Here is the square path:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)squarePathWithCenter:(CGPoint)center size:(CGFloat)size
{
    CGFloat startX = center.x-size/2;
    CGFloat startY = center.y-size/2;

    UIBezierPath *squarePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [squarePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(startX, startY)];
    [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startX+size, startY)];
    [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startX+size, startY+size)];
    [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startX, startY+size)];
    [squarePath closePath];
    return squarePath;
}
```

I apply the circle path to one of my View's layers, set the fill etc. It draws perfectly.
Then in my gestureRecognizer selector I create and run the following animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.duration = 1;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

 animation.fromValue = (__bridge id)(self.stateLayer.path);
        animation.toValue = (__bridge id)(self.stopPath.CGPath);
self.stateLayer.path = self.stopPath.CGPath;

[self.stateLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
```

As you can notice in the `circlePathWithCenter:radius:` and `squarePathWithCenter:size:` I follow the suggestion from here (to have the same number of segments and control points):
[Smooth shape shift animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429797/smooth-shape-shift-animation)

The animation looks better then in the post from above but it is still not the one I want to achieve :(

I know that I can do it with simple `CALayer` and then set appropriate level of `cornerRadius` to make a circle out of square/rectangle and after that animate `cornerRadius` property to change it from circle to square but I'm still extremaly curious if it is even possible to do it with `CAShapeLayer` and `path` animation.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: It looks like you're having the same issue as this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429797/smooth-shape-shift-animation], based on the animations—might be worth a look

Comment: hmm.. It may be - I know the question and followed the suggestion from accepted answer but still I is jus a dead end for me. I have the same number of segments/control points which I think helps since my animation is in a little bit better shape then the one from there but sill have no clue how to improve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After playing with it for a little while in the playground I noticed that each arc adds two segments to the bezier path, not just one. Moreover, calling `closePath` adds two more. So to keep the number of segments consistent, I ended up with adding fake segments to my square path. The code is in Swift, but I think it doesn't matter.

```
func circlePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath()
    circlePath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI/2), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI/2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.closePath()
    return circlePath
}

func squarePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, side: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let squarePath = UIBezierPath()
    let startX = center.x - side / 2
    let startY = center.y - side / 2
    squarePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: startX + side, y: startY))
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: startX + side, y: startY + side))
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY + side))
    squarePath.addLineToPoint(squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.closePath()
    return squarePath
}
```

[image]

Comment: good discovery re the two points, made an objective-c version.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but this might help someone.

I think its better to animate corner radius to get this effect.

```
    let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
    v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.addSubview(v1)
```

animation:

```
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fromValue = v1.layer.cornerRadius
    animation.toValue = v1.bounds.width/2
    animation.duration = 3
    v1.layer.add(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Danchoys answer, here it is for Objective-C.

**info** is a button of 60px and **infoVC** is the next ViewController being pushed:

```
    UIBezierPath * maskPath = [UIBezierPath new];
    [maskPath addArcWithCenter:info.center radius:15.0f startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) clockwise:true];
    [maskPath addArcWithCenter:info.center radius:15.0f startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) clockwise:true];
    [maskPath addArcWithCenter:info.center radius:15.0f startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) clockwise:true];
    [maskPath addArcWithCenter:info.center radius:15.0f startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180) clockwise:true];
    [maskPath closePath];

    UIBezierPath * endPath = [UIBezierPath new];
    [endPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:endPath.currentPoint];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(w, 0)];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:endPath.currentPoint];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(w, h)];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:endPath.currentPoint];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, h)];
    [endPath addLineToPoint:endPath.currentPoint];
    [endPath closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = info.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    _infoVC.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.fromValue = (id)maskPath.CGPath;
    animation.toValue = (id)endPath.CGPath;
    animation.duration = 0.3f;
    [maskLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
    [maskLayer setPath:endPath.CGPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend the library [CanvasPod](https://github.com/CanvasPod/Canvas), it also has a predefined "morph" animation and is easy to integrate. You can also check out examples on the website [canvaspod.io](http://canvaspod.io).

Answer (score 0):

This is handy for people making a recording button and want a native iOS like animation.

Instantiate this class within the UIViewController you would like to have the button. Add a `UITapGestureRecogniser` and call `animateRecordingButton` when tapped.

```
import UIKit

class RecordButtonView: UIView {

    enum RecordingState {
        case ready
        case recording
    }
            
    var currentState: RecordingState = .ready

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        // My button is 75 points in height and width so this
        // Will make a circle
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func animateRecordingButton() {
       
        var newRadius: CGFloat
        var scale: CGFloat
        
        switch currentState {
        case .ready:
            // The square radius
            newRadius = 10
            // Lets scale it down to 70%
            scale = 0.7
            currentState = .recording
        case .recording:
            // Animate back to cirlce 
            newRadius = 35
            currentState = .ready
            // Animate back to full scale
            scale = 1
        }
                    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newRadius
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        }
        
    }

}
```