# iOS Strech Animation - Where should I start looking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

How can I achieve a stretch animation look?

Where do I need to start looking? CABasicAnimation does not seem to do the trick. Something like this: is the desired effect:

http://inspirationmobile.tumblr.com/post/112168531484/sidebar-animation-by-jacub-antalik-ramotion-com

Comment: Have you had a go already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot more than a simple animation in this view.
It is used `UIKitDynamics`, but the smart thing is that the final effect is composed by the single effects of small invisible `UIView`s inside that view.
The border is a `CAShapeLayer` made by a combination of bezier path that interpolates those single views.
Each drawing cicle, the `CAShapeLayer` path is refreshed based on the position of those views.
You can find more about this effect [here](http://victorbaro.com/2014/07/vbfjellyview-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

For such a complicated shape animation look into [CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/) and [UIBezierPath](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/#fnref:penPaper). Look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788283/ios-animate-morph-shape-from-circle-to-square) that might help you to get started at least.